# oData4j sample eclipse project

Tags: java, project, odata, producer

I have downlaoded oData4J jar files from odata.org and I intend to do a sample producer, within a basic web service.

I assumed that InMemoryProducerExample.java from http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/ will do the job and most probably it is.

My problem is that I have no clue which type of project to create (Eclipse Java), how to deploy and test this example.

Does anyone have such a start up hellow world tutorial for odata step by step, or an eclipse project which use InMemoryProducerExample.java from oData. I really need a starting point and I can see one online.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to run the odata4j example is to simply checkout their project, and open it in eclipse.

If you don't have mercurial installed, install it from [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).

checkout the latest odata4j code using this mercurial command,

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/odata4j/
```

Open the project in eclipse using the maven eclipse plugin.  If you are using the latest version of eclipse, this will be installed already, it not you can install it from [here](http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse).

In eclipse, go import->maven->Existing maven projects

Then select the directory where mercurial checked out odata4j.

When eclipse finishes importing the projects, you can find InMemoryProducerExample, and right click on it to run it as a java program.  You can run any of the other examples in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, forks of odata4j which continued their lives are also available on GitHub, see https://github.com/odata4j/odata4j and my own https://github.com/vorburger/odata4j/ (which I am about to transfer to https://github.com/lukinf), which included some minor fixes for opening it in Eclipse.